# static objects in visual studio build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, win32-process

I have a problem with my visual studio - 08 build. some of the static objects are not getting instantiated. its wierd, i have a couple of files which create similar static objects. some are created some are not. when i tried to break point in the file for uncreated objects, my breakpoint is disabled.

how do i make sure all static objects are created.

Thanks,
Abhinay.

Comment: No idea, unless you post some example code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Oli: Psychic debugger on vacation, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these files directly in your main project, or are they in a static library?  When you make a static library, the linker only pulls in global variables (and calls their constructors) from object files that are somehow used.

If you do have a static library, you'll have to make sure each of the files is used by a function called by the main program.  Taking the address of some global variable in that file is one way to do this.

Comment: these files are in the static library. Adding a reference in the main project fixed it. Thanks Ben.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have several copies of your project? If you do, go to your main project folder, delete the file related to "intellisense", then reload the project. This should work.

Comment: Intellisense, and the .ncb file with the Intellisense database, don't affect the compile process at all.  They might possibly confuse the debugger, but not the run-time behavior of the program.

Comment: I was thinking it might be the reason why the breakpoints aren't working, cause they're pointing at same file but of different paths. This happens when a project was copied to another path and the same .ncb file was used in loading the project. :)